Nix - creating multiple profiles for one user
What is the correct way to create multiple nix profiles for one user?
I want to configure them differently and switch between them automatically with tools like direnv.
This is the only documentation I found about creating a new profile with an absolute path.
nix-env --switch-profile <new-absolute-path>

which makes me wonder where I should put new profile (for both NixOS / non-NixOS):
nix-env --switch-profile /nix/var/nix/profiles/myprofile
nix-env --switch-profile /nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/myprofile
nix-env --switch-profile ~/.local/state/nix/profiles/myprofile

However the answer in this question seems to imply that abolute paths can be avoided.

Generally, if you're using direnv, you don't need to manually create different profiles -- you can have a shell.nix or flake.nix in whatever project directory direnv is associated with; if you have direnv activating that shell (and assuming it's a development project, that content will presumably be in source control), what's the further need for a profile?

(If you haven't already reviewed nix-direnv, it might be worth looking at it now).

You are right, I just discovered nix-shell / devenv and they suit my purpose better. Switching the current user environment for a local terminal session does not make sense, as it will affect all other processes.

In a comment on this question, Charles Duffy suggested using nix-direnv:

Generally, if you're using direnv, you don't need to manually create different profiles -- you can have a shell.nix or flake.nix in whatever project directory direnv is associated with; if you have direnv activating that shell (and assuming it's a development project, that content will presumably be in source control), what's the further need for a profile?

This does indeed work better than switching to a separate profile in-practice, since it changes only the specific shell and doesn't affect other processes.

Thank you for giving credit to the person who gave you the idea.   But we expect answers to be freestanding.   Please [edit] your answer to explain the solution, quoting Charles, if necessary.
